# Docker tmpfs on an existing directory in the image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, tmpfs

I'm putting my first Docker image to production and can't find clear documentation on this question. I'm implementing the [OWASP Docker Security Cheat Sheet](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Docker_Security_Cheat_Sheet.html), working on [RULE #8 - Set filesystem and volumes to read-only](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Docker_Security_Cheat_Sheet.html#rule-8-set-filesystem-and-volumes-to-read-only).

My app is Ruby on Rails, so my requirements (as I understand them) are:

- I need `/tmp` to be writable
- `/tmp` is non-empty after `docker build`

So I want to...
`docker --read-only --tmpfs /application/tmp ...`

I *think* this makes the container as a whole read-only **and** makes `/tmp` writeable (for the duration of the container) **and** includes the contents of `/tmp` from the image.

Have I got this correct?

Comment: Looks correct -- easy enough to test if it works.